# What is the best partition technique for large table with TEXT column?

Tags: mysql, innodb, full-text-search, partitioning

MySQL: What is the best partition technique for large InnoDB table (around 1.5M rows) with `TEXT` type of column?

There is a `FULLTEXT` index on the `TEXT` column, which is very essential for my searching operation.

Comment: Approximately how big 'huge' is in the terms of row number?  Also, a table definition always helps.

Comment: 1.5 million records with actual .txt files saved in the table.

Comment: @Nikhil I have posted an answer, below, that directly answers the question you asked.  It seems possible, though, that you are actually asking a different question, related to performance problems you are seeing on a full text index.  If that is the case, we definitely need more information, such as the table definition and the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT` from a poorly-performing query.

Answer (score 1):

You can't partition an InnoDB table with a fulltext index, which would make intuitive sense, since it's difficult to envision how fulltext searches on (what would presumably be implemented as) multiple underlying fulltext indexes (one for each partition) would be able to give meaningful relevance and query expansion results.

> Full-text search (FTS) and foreign keys are not supported by InnoDB partitioned tables. For more information, see Section 12.9.5, “Full-Text Restrictions” and Section 18.6.2, “Partitioning Limitations Relating to Storage Engines”.
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/online-ddl-partitioning.html</sup>

The limitation applies to all storage engines.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations-storage-engines.html

Comment: It is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

if your searching is also always with a time-range or id range

then you can actually do soft-partitioning by application code.

e.g. with tables with the same structures but name like data2001,data2002,data2003

and select according tables dynamically via your application.

this also helps you scaling more easily too. the drawback is you may experience a much larger FTS index size in total.

Comment: that is possible, but needs very much code and lies ehavy on dynamic sql. As before you run a query, you need to knwo for sure that all tables exist and you need huge temp folders to hold the UNIONed tables, if you need them,. i made such a thing because the embeded Hardware didn't like big big tables, but tmost of the calculations where made in javascript. Partitioning is only in very rare cases a good idea

Comment: in op's situation, it is a requirement.